# how to retrieve class:function with clang

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

I have a `CXCursor` that marks the place where the declaration of a function in C++. I know how to get the method name, or the USR... but how can I get the Class Name (that the method is a part of)

The code that I am parsing with libclang is:

```
Number3D* ParseObjectFace::RetFaceVertex(){
    // some code... 
}
```

When I try to print the cursor information I use:

```
clang_getCString(clang_getCursorUSR(cr));
//output "c:@C@ParseObjectFace@F@RetFaceVertex#"
clang_getCString(clang_getCursorDisplayName(cr));
//output "RetFaceVertex()"
```

How can I get "ParseObjectFace" (the class name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`clang_getCursorSemanticParent`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__MANIP.html#gabc327b200d46781cf30cb84d4af3c877) to retrieve the "semantic parent" of a cursor. As quoted from the documentation:

> The semantic parent of a cursor is the cursor that semantically contains the given cursor.
>   [...]
>   In the out-of-line definition of `C::f`, the semantic parent is the the class `C`, of which this function is a member.

In your example, something like the following should work:

```
// Retrieve the semantic parent (the class in this case)
CXCursor parent = clang_getCursorSemanticParent (cr);

clang_getCString (clang_getCursorDisplayName (parent));
// Should yield "ParseObjectFace"
```